# Error opening Error opening iOS Simulator.log after bot run

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-bots

All the tests pass, but in the build log I get this:
2014-03-17 15:47:34.036 xcodebuild[19180:100b] Error opening /var/teamsserver/Library/Logs/iOS Simulator/iOS Simulator.log

Here is more of the build log:

```
2014-03-17 15:47:34.012 xcodebuild[19180:100b] [MT] DVTDevice: Starting location of devices.
2014-03-17 15:47:34.022 xcodebuild[19180:100b] [MT] DVTDevice: Adjusting available devices (setting): added = {(
)} removed = (null)
2014-03-17 15:47:34.023 xcodebuild[19180:100b] [MT] DVTDevice: Adjusting available devices (setting): added = {(
)} removed = (null)
2014-03-17 15:47:34.024 xcodebuild[19180:100b] [MT] DVTDevice: Adjusting available devices (setting): added = {(
)} removed = (null)
2014-03-17 15:47:34.025 xcodebuild[19180:100b] [MT] DVTDevice: Adjusting available devices (setting): added = {(
)} removed = (null)
2014-03-17 15:47:34.026 xcodebuild[19180:100b] [MT] DVTDevice: Adjusting available devices (inserting): added = {(
    <DVTiPhonePlaceholder: 0x7f9349f88cb0 (iOS Device | armv7)>
)} removed = (null)
2014-03-17 15:47:34.028 xcodebuild[19180:100b] [MT] DVTDevice: Adjusting available devices (inserting): added = {(
    <DVTLocalComputer: 0x7f934b8b5200 (My Mac | x86_64)>
)} removed = (null)
2014-03-17 15:47:34.036 xcodebuild[19180:100b] Error opening /var/teamsserver/Library/Logs/iOS Simulator/iOS Simulator.log
```

I know that /var/teamsserver/ does not exist, and that teamsserver is the user that the bot runs as.

Comment: Did you resolved this error?? I am having same issue... Please help me if you are managed to solve this. Thanks in advance.